# Bind SolidColorBrush to Background, binding error

Tags: c#, wpf

It seems in binding some data wrong, can someone help me out where i'm going wrong though as I can't figure it out.

Don't really need to show too much here, this is the `Binding`, I have tested the background by removing the background and just putting a colour in there, that works.

**Edit:** But with the binding there is no colour being rendered!

```
<Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color1}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
```

This is the class where the colour is set, I use SolidColorBrush as this is what the Background property expects:

```
public class notificationObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }

        }

        private string _icon;
        private string _message;
        private string _detail;
        private SolidColorBrush _color1;
        private SolidColorBrush _color2;

        public string Icon
        { get { return _icon; } set { _icon = value; OnPropertyChanged("Icon"); }}
        public string Message
        { get { return _message; } set { _message = value; OnPropertyChanged("Message"); } }
        public string Detail
        { get { return _detail; } set { _detail = value; OnPropertyChanged("Detail"); } }
        public SolidColorBrush Color1
        { get { return _color1; } set { _color1 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Color1"); } }
        public SolidColorBrush Color2
        { get { return _color2; } set { _color2 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Color2"); } }

        public notificationObject newNotification(int type, string message, string detail)
        {
            //Create new instance of object
            notificationObject x = new notificationObject();
            switch (type)
            {
                case 1:
                    //Fatal
                    x.Icon = "";
                    x.Message = message;
                    x.Detail = detail;
                    x.Color1 = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 170, 60, 18));
                    x.Color2 = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 238, 78, 16));
                    return x;
                case 2:
                    //Fatal
                    x.Icon = "";
                    x.Message = message;
                    x.Detail = detail;
                    x.Color1 = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 170, 60, 18));
                    x.Color2 = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 238, 78, 16));
                    return x;
                case 3:
                    //Unauthorized
                    x.Icon = "";
                    x.Message = message;
                    x.Detail = detail;
                    x.Color1 = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 170, 60, 18));
                    x.Color2 = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 238, 78, 16));
                    return x;
                case 4:
                    //Warning
                    x.Icon = "";
                    x.Message = message;
                    x.Detail = detail;
                    x.Color1 = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 241, 176, 24));
                    x.Color2 = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 205, 152, 28));
                    return x;
                case 5:
                    //Warning
                    x.Icon = "";
                    x.Message = message;
                    x.Detail = detail;
                    x.Color1 = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 41, 161, 213));
                    x.Color2 = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 36, 142, 184));
                    return x;
            }
            //Can't find error code
            x.Icon = "";
            x.Message = "Unable to find requested error code!";
            x.Detail = "";
            x.Color1 = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 170, 60, 18));
            x.Color2 = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 238, 78, 16));
            return x;
        }
    }
```

And obviously I set my DataContext to the instance of this class, I have got other bindings where I bind to the `Message` property and this works fine, so i'm sure it's something to do with the data type being binded.

Comment: So, what error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code attempts to create a whole new `SolidColorBrush` object, providing the `Color1` property value as the `Color` property for the new `SolidColorBrush`. Except that the `Color1` property is itself a `SolidColorBrush` and not a `Color` as needed for the `SolidColorBrush.Color` property.

It seems to me that the most obvious fix would be to just set the `Background` property directly from the `Color1` property:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Color1}"/>
```

If for some reason you really want a whole new `SolidColorBrush` object, you would have to initialize using an actual `Color` value. For example:

```
<Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color1.Color}" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

Comment: I have tried `<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Color1}">` and this doesn't work either, which is why I made the SolidColorBrush object incase that was the issue

Comment: @Martyn: please be more specific than "doesn't work". Binding the value to a `SolidColorBrush` property is a correct approach, and should work "fine". But of course note that without some change notification (e.g. `INotifyPropertyChanged`), _new_ values for the brush won't be propagated. It's not clear from your question or your comment what specifically isn't working. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, with a precise explanation of what the code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: @MartynBall I think the problem when you do it this way might be that because you are starting with uninitialised brushes, you need to be triggering a `PropertyChanged` event when you change them.

Comment: When I say it doesn't work I mean that there is no colour being rendered, sorry I thought that was a given. If this should work then it must be an issue with adding the colour in the class. What I don't understand that it can't be an `INotifyPropertyChanged` issue due to the other Properties working fine, such as `Message`

Comment: @Martyn: when binding correctly (i.e. `SolidColorBrush` source to `SolidColorBrush` target) I would expect _some_ color to be seen even without change notification, since the object starts out with some brush object values in the constructor. Again, without a good [mcve], it's not possible to understand the question fully, never mind answer completely. I will point out that really, the kind of things you are doing here seem more appropriate to implement using a XAML `Style`, with `Triggers` that correspond to the various values passed into the constructor now.

Comment: Just found the issue, im an idiot. The alpha on the colours where set to `0`... `new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 170, 60, 18));` It now works... sorry about that, thanks for the help. I will mark this as the Answer.

Comment: @MartynBall: glad you figured it out. For what it's worth, I probably should have noticed the 0 alpha values too; I wasn't looking closely at the brush initialization, rather just at the binding. Due to the "typographical error" nature of the problem, it's unlikely this question is going to be useful to future readers. I recommend that you close/delete the question using the "off-topic/typographical error" reason (I will vote for closing now myself).

Answer (score 1):

Your `Color1` property is of type `SolidColorBrush` but you are binding to the `Color` property of your `SolidColorBrush` which has type `System.Windows.Media.Color`.

You could bind the background property directly to the `SolidColorBrush` you are creating at the moment or you could change those properties to expose a `System.Windows.Media.Color` instead and keep your XAML as it is now.

Note, since you have setters to change those colours, that you'll need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you want any changes to be reflected in the view.